# how to access tag with css selector in selenium using descendant(>>)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, descendant

xxx, yyy is the things that i want to access with css selector in selenium

```
xxx=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#contents > div.tabWrap.pdtTabWrap.fixed >             div.tabContents > section.tabCont.active >
```

div > div > div.prdDetailConWrap > div.prdType.prdType11 > div.imgWrap.imgCrop > img')

```
yyy=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#contents > div.tabWrap.pdtTabWrap.fixed > div.tabContents > section.tabCont.active >
```

div > div > div > div.prd_sec.prd_top_type01.sec01.mt0 > div > div.top_img_box > img')

xxx, yyy look similar

is it possible to access similar things(same start point, different middle point, same end point)
with just one line using descendant(>>)?

i ran

driver.find_element(
By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#contents > div.tabWrap.pdtTabWrap.fixed >             div.tabContents > section.tabCont.active >> img')

but error occured

Answer (score 0):

Try using a space instead:

```
driver.find_element( By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#contents > div.tabWrap.pdtTabWrap.fixed > div.tabContents > section.tabCont.active img')
```

You can read more here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators

Comment: it is helpful thanks. another question                                                                       
can i handle nth:child(i) with curly brace?                                                            like for i in range(5):                                                                              
driver.find_elements( #pdtList > li:nth-child({i}) > div > a > div.pdtThumb > span > img).get_attribute('src) )